# How to call java action class from both onload & onclick events in a single jsp

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, struts

I need to call a java action class when my jsp loads(during onload) & when button is clicked in jsp .

Two different scenarios in a same jsp but parameters differ.Unfortunately the parameters are not getting passed to action class from jsp during click event ,whereas it works fine for me during onload. Where i went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

How did u called the action? Here i used [jQuery ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for send the request. On page load do like this,

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
                                                                </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var parameter = $("#textBox").val();
    $.ajax({
        url : "navigation.do?parameter=showNavigation&value="+parameter,
        type : "POST",
        success : function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

And on button click,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#buttonId").click(function() {
    var parameter1 = $("#textBox").val();
    $.ajax({
        url : "navigation.do?parameter=showNavigation&value="+parameter1,
        type : "POST",
        success : function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```